# Lower bound $\max\{n\geq 1|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\leq T\}$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, stopping-times, upper-lower-bounds

Let $T\geq 0$ and let $(X_i)_i$ be a sequence of iid non negative random variables such that $E[X_1]>0$.

Let $\tau = \max\{n\geq 1|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\leq T\}$.

How could I upper bound $E[T-\sum_{i=1}^\tau X_i] = T - E[\tau]E[X_1]$ ?

Is it true that $ \frac{E[\tau]}{E[X]}= \lfloor T\rfloor$?

Comment: I think this might help https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177697092

Comment: There's a subtle but extremely important difference between the problem considered in the linked paper and the problem @product asked: the above is $\max\{n : \sum \leq T \}$ while the other is $\min\{ n : \sum > T\}$.  The latter is a stopping time while the former is not.  See my answer for how this breaks things.

Comment: I'm sorry @MarcusM but isn't $\max\{n:\sum\leq T\}$ equal to $\min\{n:\sum>T\}-1$?

Comment: @MarcusM are you sure? (The $-1$ is written in my comment). Also, does it mean that if I use $\min\{n:\sum>T\}-1$ instead of $\max\{n:\sum\leq T\}$ I have a stopping time and the formula is correct?

Comment: @MarcusM $\max = 1$ and $\min - 1 = 1$...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106687/discussion-between-product-and-marcus-m).

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the second part, and an argument that there should not be a nice answer to the first part; indeed the equality you state is incorrect.  We need not have $E[T - \sum_{i = 1}^\tau X_i] = T - E[\tau]E[X]$ since $\tau$ is *not* a stopping time.

Let $Z_n$ be the random variable with $P(Z_n = 1/n) = (n-1)/n$ and $P(Z_n = n) = 1/n$.  Then as $n \to \infty$ we have $E[Z_n] \sim 1$.

Let $\tau_n$ denote the corresponding $\tau$ variable; i.e., take $X_j$ to be i.i.d. copies of $Z_n$ and set $\tau_n = \max\{m : \sum_{j = 1}^m X_j \leq T\}.$
For any fixed $T$---e.g. $T = 1$---we will have $E[\tau_n] \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.  This also shows that the equality you state is not correct, since this demonstrates that the right-hand-side may be negative even though the left-hand-side is non-negative.

Comment: The $(X_n)$ you have provided are not iid.

Comment: yes I'm aware.  My point is take i.i.d copies of $X_j$ and repeat this experiment for each $j$.  As you do this, the corresponding $\tau$ variable will blow up.  I will edit to make this more apparent.

Comment: Never mind, I see what you're trying to say. It may be a good idea to edit this for clarity (e.g. maybe you would want to write $X_i^{(n)}$ instead of $X_n$).

Comment: Sorry, I commented at essentially the same time as you :-)